# Cross coverage inheriting iff clause of coverpoint

Tags: system-verilog

I'm seeing an issue with one of my crosses inheriting the "iff" clause of one of it's constituent coverpoints.

```
covergroup cg @(LdReqVld_d1);
    LdReq_cp : coverpoint LdReqVld_d1 iff (!LdReqCancel);
    LdOp_cp  : coverpoint LdReqOp_d1  iff (LdReqVld_d1 && !LdReqCancel);
    LdCancel_cp : coverpoint LdReqCancel;
    CrossCancel : cross LdOp_cp, LdCancel_cp;
```

I'm seeing the `CrossCancel` is never hitting any bin with `LdReqCancel == 1` even when I expect it to, and I suspect it's because the `LdOp_cp` is crossed with contains the `iff (LdReqVld_d1 && !LdReqCancel)`, so the `CrossCancel` "secretly" has that `iff` guarding it too. Is this the expected behavior? And if so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but what you see is what I would expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `cross` is technically between bins of a `coverpoint`, not the coverpoint itself. From the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) section 19.6 Defining cross coverage:

> Cross coverage of a set of N coverage points is defined as the
> coverage of all combinations of all bins associated with the N
> coverage points

So if a coverpoint bin does not get sampled because of an `iff` guard, the cross bin is guarded as well.

Comment: I see, thanks. So the only way to fix this would be to create another coverpoint for LdReqOp that does sample when LdReqCancel is 1?

Comment: You don't need another coverpoint. You can cross `LdReqVld_d1` directly. But does that really make sense to cover a cross bin that not being covered in a coverpoint?